# Unable to launch UML plugin in eclipse

Tags: java

Unable to create the selected preference page.
com/objectaid/uml/cls/editor/ClassDiagramPreferencePage : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

This message pops up and I am unable to generate the class diagram.
Do help me out

Answer (score 0):

It seems the Java version you are using is different as what expect by UML plugin. Please correct the Java version from the below checklist.

1) Correct the JRE version from the Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JRE
2) Correct the JDK Compiler version from the Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler